# Powershell - Join multiple commands

Tags: powershell, office365

Get-MsolSubscription gives me total number of licenses

```
$Result=""   
$Results=@()   
$Subscriptions= Get-MsolSubscription | foreach{
 $SubscriptionName=$_.SKUPartNumber
 $SubscribedOn=$_.DateCreated
 $ExpiryDate=$_.NextLifeCycleDate
 $Status=$_.Status
 $TotalLicenses=$_.TotalLicenses
 $Result=@{'Subscription Name'=$SubscriptionName;'Total Licenses'=$TotalLicenses}
 $Results+= New-Object PSObject -Property $Result
 }
```

Above code works fine, now i want to combine output of above command with output of Get-MsolAccountSku because that command gives me number of actually used licenses

So i modified code as below:

```
$Result=""   
$Results=@()   
$Subscriptions= Get-MsolSubscription | foreach{
 $SubscriptionName=$_.SKUPartNumber
 $SubscribedOn=$_.DateCreated
 $ExpiryDate=$_.NextLifeCycleDate
 $Status=$_.Status
 $TotalLicenses=$_.TotalLicenses
 $consumedLicences = Get-MsolAccountSku | foreach {
  $consumed = $_.ConsumedUnits
  $name = $_.SkuPartNumber
  } | where {$_.name -like $SubscriptionName }
 $Result=@{'Subscription Name'=$SubscriptionName;'Total Licenses'=$TotalLicenses;'Used'=$consumed}
 $Results+= New-Object PSObject -Property $Result
 }
```

Problem is that for all licences i'm getting same value for used column

```
Total Licenses Subscription Name              Used
-------------- -----------------              ----
            48 VISIOCLIENT                       9
            16 VISIOCLIENT                       9
         10000 STREAM                            9
            50 EMSPREMIUM                        9
         10000 POWERAPPS_INDIVIDUAL_USER         9
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `foreach` block after `Get-MsolAccountSku` never outputs anything, but it always overwrites `$consumed` on each iteration - hence the repeated count.

Change it to:

```
$Results = Get-MsolSubscription | ForEach-Object {
    # Get the part number and total licenses
    $SubscriptionName = $_.SKUPartNumber
    $TotalLicenses = $_.TotalLicenses

    # Count used licenses
    $consumedLicences = Get-MsolAccountSku | Where-Object {
        $_.SKUPartNumber -like $SubscriptionName
    } | ForEach-Object {
        $_.ConsumedUnits
    } |Measure-Object -Sum |Select-Object -Expand Sum
    
    # Output resulting object 
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        'Subscription Name' = $SubscriptionName
        'Total Licenses' = $TotalLicenses
        'Used' = $consumedLicences
    }
}
```

I took the liberty of simplifying your code slightly in the process, but the meat of it is this:

```
$consumedLicences = Get-MsolAccountSku | Where-Object {
    $_.SKUPartNumber -like $SubscriptionName
} | ForEach-Object {
    $_.ConsumedUnits
} |Measure-Object -Sum |Select-Object -Expand Sum
```

Here, we apply the filtering with `Where-Object` *before doing anything else* - while each output object from `Get-MsolAccountSku` still has it's properties intact. Then we use `ForEach-Object` to extract the value of `ConsumedUnits`, and finally we use `Measure-Object` to sum all counts (it's unclear to me whether `Get-MsolAccountSku |Where-Object ...` results in multiple matches).

If there's only one, you can either leave it as is (sum of one value is just the value it self), or you can remove everything after `ForEach-Object { ... }` completely:

```
$consumedLicences = Get-MsolAccountSku | Where-Object {
    $_.SKUPartNumber -like $SubscriptionName
} | ForEach-Object {
    $_.ConsumedUnits
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort, i don't need sum, just need ConsumedUnit property for every license, i changed `$consumedLicences = Get-MsolAccountSku | Where-Object {
        $_.Name -like $SubscriptionName
    } | ForEach-Object {
        $_.ConsumedUnits
    } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty ConsumedUnits` and getting nothing as output for consumedLicences. With your original code getting 0

Comment: Remove `Select-Object -Expand...` part, it's not needed - since we dereference `$_.ConsumedUnits`, the output of `ForEach-Object` is the raw numerical value. In other words, there's no properties to expand

Comment: thanks, it works now, it was typo in your answer, i'll post whole code as another answer. Thank you !

Comment: @overflowed Great! Please let me know where the typo is (or suggest an edit to my answer) so it can be corrected :-)

Comment: `$_.Name -like $SubscriptionName` should be `$_.SkuPartNumber -like $SubscriptionName`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Mathias R. Jessen, here is complete code which works fine now:

```
$Result=""   
$Results=@()   
$Subscriptions= Get-MsolSubscription | foreach{
 $SubscriptionName=$_.SKUPartNumber
 $SubscribedOn=$_.DateCreated
 $ExpiryDate=$_.NextLifeCycleDate
 $Status=$_.Status
 $TotalLicenses=$_.TotalLicenses
 $consumedLicences = Get-MsolAccountSku | Where-Object {
        $_.SkuPartNumber -like $SubscriptionName
    } | ForEach-Object {
        $_.ConsumedUnits
    }
 $Result=@{'Subscription Name'=$SubscriptionName;'Total Licenses'=$TotalLicenses;'Used'=$consumedLicences}
 $Results+= New-Object PSObject -Property $Result
 }
```